# OpenLayers Point (x,y) to Long Lat

Tags: openlayers

How do you convert OpenLayers.Geometry.Point (X and Y) to a output a long and lat value?

- I am trying to add this into a .net DbGeography object

Comment: It depends what the input projection is. There is no such thing as an OpenLayers basemap or projection, you can use any you like, unlike say in Google Maps.

Comment: Hi John, The projection is EPSG:4326 - Open Layers version 2, does OpenLayers have anything built in to do this functionaility or is it a case of another service?

Comment: OK, so 4326 is lat/lon, so no reprojection necessary. Are you just asking how to access the geometry values of an OpenLayers point?

Comment: I'm returning a OpenLayers.Geometry.Point then using getCenterLonLat() method on the bounds. this then returns something like 'lon=-47263.941325996,lat=6745082.9989192'. straight away i can see this doesn't look like a long lat, I tried to put it into a DbGeography object and as expected this was returned {"24201: Latitude values must be between -90 and 90 degrees."}

Comment: Look at the [transform method](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Geometry/Point-js.html#OpenLayers.Geometry.Point.transform). Your coordinates are in 3857 (Google Maps), which is one of the built in transforms in OpenLayers.

Comment: Ah ok, is it something along the lines of.. (point is my OpenLayers.Geometry.Point variable)

point.feature(this get projection? , new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"))

Comment: point.feature(OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:3857"),OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")) ??

Comment: var newpoint = pt.transform(OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:3857"),OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:432‌​6")):

Comment: hmmm, didn't quite work. returns the same :( 

newpoint.bounds.getCenterLonLat();

returns

OpenLayers.LonLat.OpenLayers.Class.initialize {lon: -47970.983837505, lat: 6743688.0231493, initialize: function, toString: function, toShortString: function…}

Comment: Please could you add a code sample of what you are doing?